# SPA extensible by user

Tags: node.js, vue.js

In reference to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/400580/how-to-write-an-application-extensible-by-the-user-in-vue-js

I need help with code.

Struct of files

```
src
├── App.vue
├── assets
│   └── logo.png
├── components
│   └── HelloWorld.vue
└── main.js
public
├── assets
│   └── gw
│       └── plugin
│           └── component.vue
├── favicon.ico
└── index.html
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="path" />
    <component :is="componentInstance" />
    {{publicPath}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      path: "assets/gw/plugin/component.vue",
      publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
    };
  },
  computed: {
    componentInstance() {
      return () => import(this.publicPath + this.path);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

File `public/assets/gw/plugin/component.vue` shuold be created by user and imported in `App.vue` in production env.

Unfortunately this solution causes error

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () {
        return __webpack_require__("./src lazy recursive")(_this.publicPath + _this.path);
      }
Reason: Error: Cannot find module '/assets/gw/plugin/component.vue'
```

How can I import users's component?

This works fine, but I need to pass path at runtime.

```
computed: {
    componentInstance() {
      return () => import("../public/assets/gw/plugin/component.vue");
    }
  }
```

feel free to play with my problem example
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-import-sfc-at-runtime-jft1z

Comment: BTW, the path to component file i'm going to pass as property ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is easy. [Read this article.](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/)

We need to load component from remote location:

```js
// src/utils/external-component.js
export default async function externalComponent(url) {
    const name = url.split('/').reverse()[0].match(/^(.*?)\.umd/)[1];

    if (window[name]) return window[name];

    window[name] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(window[name]);
        });
        script.addEventListener('error', () => {
            reject(new Error(`Error loading ${url}`));
        });
        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });

    return window[name];
}
```